# Select text in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rangy

I need to be able to select text in a div given the cursor position and a number. I have already tried many examples here, they have a problem: if you are at the start of a new line, the selection goes from the last character of the previous line until the current character (caret position), if there are any line breaks in between they will be wiped out when inserting text after the selection is made, so the text is inserted at the end of the previous line..

I'm using the following code from Tim Down, but it has this major caveat, it doesn't skip any line breaks, so when selecting the range, these are selected as well. I need to find a way to select just the text, and not extend the selection until the previous character.

```
function createRangeFromCharacterIndices(containerEl, start, end) {
    var charIndex = 0,
      range = document.createRange(),
      foundStart = false,
      stop = {};

    range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
    range.collapse(true);

    function traverseTextNodes(node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
            if (!foundStart && start >= charIndex && start <= nextCharIndex) {
                range.setStart(node, start - charIndex);
                foundStart = true;
            }
            if (foundStart && end >= charIndex && end <= nextCharIndex) {
                range.setEnd(node, end - charIndex);
                throw stop;
            }
            charIndex = nextCharIndex;
        } else {
            for (var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
                traverseTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        traverseTextNodes(containerEl);
    } catch (ex) {
        if (ex == stop) {
            return range;
        } else {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm misinterpreting the code, `createRangeFromCharacterIndices` is interpreting `start` and `end` as a person would, just by looking at the text displayed by the browser. That is, if you have `foo<strong>bar</strong>`, then the `b` letter is considered to be character 3. And it converts it to what DOM routines want: `b` would be the character 0 of the text node for `bar`. It would be good to make this explicit in the question instead of letting folks have to read the code to figure it out. Also, what constitutes a "new line" in your text? A `<br>`? The start of a new `<p>`?

Comment: Since you've tagged this Rangy, did you look at the Rangy TextRange module?

Comment: @Louis <br> will be a new line. The case is that in `text<br/>text2` when selecting the first 't' in text2, it will also select the <br/>, thus removing the line break

Comment: @TimDown I looked at the module but couldn't get it to work, do you have any example? Thanks